# Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: [...] version for the right syntax to use near 'order (id)' at line 1

Tags: mysql, hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, many-to-one

This exception is related with

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=update
```

I am not trying to save any data yet

In my opinion mappings are correct but still exception is thrown:

org.hibernate.tool.schema.spi.CommandAcceptanceException: Error executing DDL "create table order (id bigint not null auto_increment, order_date date, user_id bigint, primary key (id)) engine=MyISAM" via JDBC Statement

Caused by: java.sql.SQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'order (id)' at line 1

My mappings looks like:

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class BaseEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    private Long id;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Order")
@Table(name = "order")
public class Order extends BaseEntity {

    private LocalDate orderDate;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "order", cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    private List<OrderedTicket> orderedTickets = new ArrayList<>();

    private Long userId;

}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "OrderedTicket")
@Table(name = "ordered_ticket")
public class OrderedTicket extends BaseEntity {

    private Integer amount;

    @OneToOne
    @JoinColumn(name="ticket_id")
    private Ticket ticket;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_id")
    private Order order;

}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
@Entity(name = "Ticket")
@Table(name = "ticket")
public class Ticket extends BaseEntity {

    @Enumerated(value = EnumType.STRING)
    private TicketType type;
    private Integer price;
    private Integer totalAmmount;
    private Integer inStock;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = {
            CascadeType.DETACH,
            CascadeType.MERGE,
            CascadeType.PERSIST,
            CascadeType.REFRESH
    })
    @JoinColumn(name = "event_id")
    Event event;

    @Builder
    public Ticket(TicketType type, Integer price, Integer totalAmmount, Integer inStock, Event event) {
        this.type = type;
        this.price = price;
        this.totalAmmount = totalAmmount;
        this.inStock = inStock;
        this.event = event;
    }

}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't name your table ORDER because ORDER is a reserved SQL keyword.

You could do it but then you will always have to enclose ORDER in quotes.

Please check out the MySQL Manual for all reserved keywords:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html

Answer (score 5):

Try to surround the order table name with backticks. Otherwise, the engine will keep throwing errors due to reserved keyword:

```
@Table(name = "`order`")
public class Order extends BaseEntity {
```

Comment: Thanks @Maciej this  solution solved my build problem creating an order table with Hibernate and MySQL

Answer (score 1):

`ORDER` is a reserverd  word  (used for ORDER BY clause) 
you should change table name eg using a different table name

```
create table customer_order (
  id bigint not null auto_increment
, order_date date
, user_id bigint
, primary key (id)) 
engine=MyISAM"
```

or if you really need this table name  use backtics  around the tablename

```
create table `order` (
  id bigint not null auto_increment
, order_date date
, user_id bigint
, primary key (id)) 
engine=MyISAM"
```